# Woocommerce add products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce, divi-theme

Im using the divi theme with Woocommerce. I need to  know how to add more than one product from my home page, avoiding going to the product page. Just using add to the cart function or similar.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<a href="/?add-to-cart=111" data-quantity="1" class="button">Add to cart</a>
```